# doh robot unavailable after running previous instance

Tags: javascript, dojo, automated-tests, doh

I grabbed the latest dojo code to play around with the DOH robot. I have installed two exact copies of the dojo/dijit/dojox/util package: one on the root level of my server and one under /js/.

```
localhost/dojo
         /dijit
         /dojox
         /util
```

Then another copy under:

```
localhost/js/dojo
          js/dijit
          js/dojox
          js/util
```

When I navigate to   http://localhost/util/doh/tests/Robot.html
, the DOH robot initializes fine and everything runs (the mouse moves, tests pass, etc.)

When I try to do the same thing, only in the /js folder, (eg,  http://localhost/js/util/doh/tests/Robot.html) I almost always get the error:

```
Error: doh.robot not available; skipping test.
```

Sometimes the robot will load up fine and pass all of the tests. Sometimes I will have the Java popup asking permission to use the robot (when this happens, I get the doh.robot unavailable error.)

Any idea what could be causing this, or some tips to keep this from happening?

I have tried the following things (and even tried all combinations of these steps):

1. clear firefox settings (ctl+shif+del, check all)
2. f5, ctl+f5
3. kill the java process
4. restart the browser
5. restart the server
6. restart the computer
7. tried all different browsers, same effect
8. recompiled/resigned the DOHRobot.jar

The thing that really irks me is that I have seen it work fine before, so I know that java and plugins are installed correctly.

I can always go back to the top level and run the robot just fine; the problem only happens when I am in the /js/ directory.

Any tips would be great! Thanks

**EDIT** I think it works now. The problem was that I was recompiling the robot but not signing the JAR correctly. (Check the .bat file when you compile and notice how it looks for the keystore in the directory above you; when I was making the keystore it saved to the default user directory.)  Even though I wasn't changing any of the java code, the JAR was still signed incorrectly.  Also if anyone does this, one step I forgot to include was to *clear the Java cache!* I'm not sure how much that matters.

Anyway I think this is solved; it looks like I wasn't exactly describing the problem correctly either.

Comment: I suggest filing a ticket at bugs.dojotoolkit.org (there are DNS problems right now... maybe try tomorrow)

Comment: Hey peller thanks for the suggestion, although I don't think it's a bug. Seems like I was leaving a bit out when describing the problem (like the fact that I recompiled the robot.) I guess it just goes to show that sometimes the best thing to do is take a break and sleep on it.